# Update (Ubuntu) VPS from github repository?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, vps

I am just getting starting with git and I got everything set up and running on my local machine. What I would like to do now, after I make a revision on my local machine, is to be able to download the code (a WordPress theme) to /var/www/ on my VPS. Is this something that can be easily done with git or would there be a better way using another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://sebduggan.com/blog/deploy-your-website-changes-using-git/) page shows one way of doing it with a post receive hook.

- Create a file post-receive in the hooks directory of your repository:

> #!/bin/sh
>    GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/webroot/of/mywebsite git checkout -f

- Make sure the target directory exists, as Git won’t create it for you. Finally, set permissions on the file:

> $ chmod +x hooks/post-receive